# Como obtener el dato retornado de una invocación por GetMethod. c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Por ejemplo tengo una clase serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class Tools 
{   
    public string name = "NAME_RANDOM";

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Después hago este método genérico

```
public bool Find<T>( T data, string search )
{
    return ( data.GetType().GetMethod("GetName") == search ) ?
    true : false;               
}
```

Y ejecuto el script

```
public Tools tools; // Atributo público de la clase;

Find<Tools>(tools, "NAME_RANDOM");
```

Mi pregunta es: Como se si GetMethod me devuelve el String "NAME_RANDOM";

Comment: No se si esta bien planteada el condicional de Find<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `MethodInfo#Invoke` para ejecutar el metodo y obtener el valor de retorno y asi poder hacer la compraracion:

```
public bool Find<T>( T data, string search )
{
    String resultadoMetodo = data.GetType().GetMethod("GetName").Invoke(data, null).ToString()0;
    return ( reusultadoMetodo == search ) ?
    true : false;               
}
```

En tu ejemplo `data.GetType().GetMethod("GetName")` retorna objeto de tipo [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), no el valor de retorno.

Comment: Gracias, esta la solución; en el caso de que quiera obtener el atributo "name" de la clase tools uso GetProperty, no?

Comment: `name` no es un atributo sino un campo(field en ingles) y `GetProperty` es para propiedades. Para los campos seria `data.GetType().GetField("name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue()`

Comment: Gracias aprendí mucho.